# Multiply with nested function

Tags: javascript

I am practicing JS and I have a task to multiply elements from the list mult([1,2,3])(2) => [2,4,6]. As I see I should multiply with nested function, but seems like I do something wrong, I am getting error `TypeError: mult(...) is not a function`

```
function mult(a){
  function num(b){
    res=[]
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
      res.push(a[i]*b)
    }
    return res
  }
}
console.log(mult([1,2,3])(2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mult` defines a function (`num`) and then does **nothing else**.

Your code expects `mult` to *return* a function, but you have no `return` statement, so you return `undefined`.

`return` the function you create inside it.

---

Note that "Create an array with values that are the same as another array but after a transformation" is exactly what [the `map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is designed for.

So you could rewrite your code as:

```js
const mult = a => b => a.map(value => value * b);
console.log(mult([1,2,3])(2))
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is because you are not `return`ning the function num, just declaring it.

So mult([...]) returns `undefined` and you are trying to execute it.

To fix it, just return the function `num`/